# AngularJS: display a block of html after button click

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

I am trying to write a controller to handle the button click of the "New" button. The goal is for the lower block of code (starting `<div ng-show="buttonClick">`) to be initially hidden. When "New" button is clicked I would like the lower block of code to appear.

The problem I'm having is that the lower block of code is visible when I load the page. It is never hidden.

```
{% extends "base.html" %}


{% block content %}
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>

  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
        <h2>Ratings</h2>
        <table class="table table-bordered">
          <thead>
          <tr>
            <th>Beer Name</th>
            <th>Beer Rating</th>
            <th>Notes</th>
            <th>Brewer</th>
          </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
          {% for rating in ratings %}
            <tr>
              <td>{{ rating.beer_name }}</td>
              <td>{{ rating.score }}</td>
              <td>{{ rating.notes }}</td>
              <td>{{ rating.brewer }}</td>
              <td><a href="{% url 'rating-edit' rating.id  %}" class="btn btn-primary" value="{{ rating.id }}" name="edit">Edit</a></td>
              <td><a class="btn btn-primary" href="{% url 'rating-delete' rating.id  %}" value="{{ rating.id }}" name="delete" >Delete</a></td>
            </tr>
          {% endfor %}
          </tbody>
        </table>
        <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
        <a ng-model="buttonClick" ng-click="is_clicked()" class="btn btn-primary">New</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>






<div ng-show="buttonClick" >
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-10 col-sm-offset-1">
        <h2>Enter a new rating</h2>
        <form role="form" method="post">
          {% csrf_token %}
          <p>Beer Name: {{ form.beer_name }}</p>
          <p>Score: {{ form.score }}</p>
          <p>Notes: {{ form.notes }}</p>
          <p>Brewer: {{ form.brewer }}</p>
          <p><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button></p>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
</div>

<script>
        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope){
          $scope.buttonClick = false;
          $scope.is_clicked = function() {
            $scope.buttonClick=true;
            console.log($scope.buttonClick)
         }
        })
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: What is not working?

Comment: @GG. The lower block is showing when I load the page. It is never hidden.

Comment: Are there any errors in your browser's console? If you add a `console.log($scope.buttonClick)` in your controller, what is logged?

Comment: @GG. I added the line and ran it. Still no errors are appearing in my terminal. (That is where they'd appear?)

Comment: They would appear in your browser console (in Google Chrome: right click on your page > inspect an element > tab "console")

Comment: Yes, I do have an error: Uncaught SyntaxError

Comment: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token )
And it is referring the the 5th line down starting with "app.controller..."

Comment: Yep I posted an answer about that. :) Tell me if it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On this line

```
app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope)) {
```

Remove the last `)`

---

When your code will work, you will probably have a "blink" effect with your block. It will appear at the loading of the page, then it will disappear when Angular will start. If you have the "blink" effect, you will need to add `ng-cloack` on the block.

```
<div ng-show="buttonClick" ng-cloak>
```

Comment: Okay! Awesome, now I'm free of that and getting new errors. haha

Comment: Ahah cool! You'll see that your browser console will help you a lot! :)

Comment: You can upvote my answer by clicking on the up-arrow on the left

Comment: Update: no more errors, but the code just doesn't hide the form.

Comment: So when I added the ng-cloak I have the opposite problem. The block is hidden upon load but when I hit the "New" button it doesn't appear.

Comment: There is also a typo issue with `ng-click"is_clicked()"`: operator `=` is missing

Comment: Thanks, I fixed that but I'm still having the same problem.

Comment: In this line `$scope.is_clicked = function() { return $scope.buttonClick=true; }`, remove the `return`. If it still not working, add a `console.log($scope.buttonClick)` at the end of this function and look the value in your console. It might have nothing in your console (then you never pass inside of the function).

Comment: When I place the line console.log($scope.buttonClick) just after the closing bracket of is_clicked() my console shows: false.

Comment: And before the closing bracket?

Comment: Before I get nothing

Comment: Even when you click on the button?

Comment: I get true after I click on the button.

Comment: I'm not sure but you can try to move your script **after** your block. Generally we have all the scripts at the end of the document, just before the closing `</body>`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! I've added the rest of the file thinking maybe it's something before that could be affecting it. It must be some small thing.

Comment: Hello, in your last edit the div with `ng-show="buttonClick"` is outside of the application. It has to be inside `<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">[HERE]</div>`.

Comment: It works! Now my submit button does nothing...but now that works! haha

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably try it like this (untested):

```
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">
       <div><a ng-click"buttonClick = !buttonClick" class="btn btn-primary">New</a></div>
       <script>
       var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
       app.controller('myCtrl', function($scope)) {
         $scope.buttonClick = false;
       }
       </script>
```

Comment: Thanks. I just gave that a try and it still isn't hidden. I hope I gave enough information in the post.